# Truck trailer angling while riding

Tags: xna, physics

I am about creating a new game with trucks (2D, top-view).

I made a truck moving by keyboard and a stiff trailer attached to it. My goal is to make a loosy trailer like in real trucks with external trailers to attach. I tried to find something at google (even some formulas) but nothing found. Any ideas what angles, what delays should I make to change trailer's angle? Maybe I am thinking wrong?

P.S. I use XNA.

Comment: The equations of motion for two connected rigid bodies are quite complex actually. You need to frame your problem (variables, simulation and results) in order to answer effectively.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out myself. I made calculations between angle of truck and trailer, made some additions/substractions and it looks like behaving naturally.